# Dynamic show hide code for dynamic content angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

Run below code as it is, Code is working fine but i want the same functionality without polluting angularjs code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="newapp" ng-controller="newctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="x in names">
            <div  data-ng-click="toggleCompanyArr(['nav_' + x.id])"><a href="">This is id : {{x.id}}</a></div>
            <div id="nav_{{x.id}}" style="display:none">{{x.firstname}} {{x.lastname}}</div><br><Br><Br>
        </div>
    </body>

<script>
var app = angular.module('newapp',[]);
app.controller('newctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.names=[
        {"id":"1","firstname":"Akhilesh","lastname":"Kumar"},
        {"id":"2","firstname":"Aman","lastname":"Kumar"},
        {"id":"3","firstname":"Mithilesh","lastname":"Kumar"}
    ];  
    $scope.toggleCompanyArr = function(val){
        $("#"+val).toggle();    
    };
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery to show/hide div, you could simply use `ng-show` here.

For achieving this you need to add `show` flag on each element of the `names` collection (you don't necessary to add new `show` property to your collection, if you don't add `show: false` prop in your each names element, angular will take care of this), and toggle `show` flag on click of the element. Thereafter use `x.show` flag inside `ng-show` directive to show & hide div.

Basically on initial load `x.show` value either `undefined` or `false` so anyhow it is going to hide the all element content on load. When you click on element `ng-click` directive will flag to `x.show = true` and that element will get shown.

The other advantage behind this approach is, you could have state of your each element in its object.

Suppose you have `akhilesh` option selected then it will have `{"id":"1","firstname":"Akhilesh","lastname":"Kumar", show: true},` & other will have `show: false` if those element are not clicked.

**Markup**

```
<div  data-ng-click="x.show = !x.show">
    <a href="">This is id : {{x.id}}</a>
</div>
<div ng-show="x.show">
    {{x.firstname}} {{x.lastname}}
</div>
```

[**Reference link**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2487-filter-vs-nghide-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm)

Comment: Hello Pankaj, Thanks for your quick reply but i have one query. As code is dynamic, How data-ng-click= x.show =!x.show wil bind with ng-show="x.show"?

Comment: @AkhileshKumar yes..the `show` property will get added to the `x` which is each element of `ng-repeat`, you could look at the updated answer

Comment: its working fine..... thanks, But i did't got the concept. Please refer some link so that i will get the concept behind it or if possible please explain it.

Comment: you can use ngShow and ngHide

Comment: @AlainIb that is what I shown in my answer.. does I missed something?

Comment: @AkhileshKumar look at the updated answer..and also added link which will give you better idea how it works. :)

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar no not missing at all. i just want to say that both function exist for OP

Comment: @Pankaj: What is the value of 'x' in synax data-ng-click="x.show = !x.show".  According to your comment above it will be {"id":"1","firstname":"Akhilesh","lastname":"Kumar", show: true}.  but what if i will use data-ng-click="d.show = !d.show" ?

Comment: x means your current element of ng-repeat

Comment: If it is d.show the it would not work..because d variable is not there in ng-repeat context..as x does stands for each element if ng-repeat.

Comment: @pankaj: below code is also working fine... any comment? <div  data-ng-click="d.show = !d.show">
    <a href="">This is id : {{x.id}}</a>
</div>
<div ng-show="d.show">
    {{x.firstname}} {{x.lastname}}
</div>

Comment: @AkhileshKumar yes..that will work as `d` stands for nothing but, when you use `d.show=!d.show`, angular defines that object for you(which wasn't exist) using `$parse('d.show')`..so basically it will create `d` object with `show` property.. but would not recommend you to follow this approach. because `x` is object which has your element level data like  `{"id":"1","firstname":"Akhilesh","lastname":"Kumar"}` so putting that show property in `x` object would make sense..

Comment: @AkhileshKumar you are going to accept answer or not?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Answer is already accepted that's why i already added REPUTATION in your answer.

Comment: @AkhileshKumar no man..look at this link [how to accept answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)